# IF Condition in XSLT by comparing the count of sub node in parent node

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am trying to perform loop A or Loop B based on the count of the nodes

```
 empjobcount -> "count(employmentNav/EmpEmployment/compInfoNav/EmpCompensation/startDate)"  
 compcount -> "count(employmentNav/EmpEmployment/jobInfoNav/EmpJob/startDate)"
```

how to pass count to the parameter in order to perform if condition. 
Below is causing syntax error.

```
<xsl:if test= {"count(employmentNav/EmpEmployment/compInfoNav/EmpCompensation/startDate)" ge "count(employmentNav/EmpEmployment/jobInfoNav/EmpJob/startDate)"} >
</xsl:if>
```

Pseudocode:
if empjobcount > compcount.
loopA.
else.
loopB.
endif.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the curly braces, i.e. use `test="count(employmentNav/EmpEmployment/compInfoNav/EmpCompensation/startDate) >= count(employmentNav/EmpEmployment/jobInfoNav/EmpJob/startDate)"`. I also think you need `xsl:choose/xsl:when test/xsl:otherwise` instead of a single `xsl:if` if you really need to execute two different branches of code.

As you have tagged your question for XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 3.0 it might be possible to solve things at the XPath expression level with the `if (conditional expression) then expression1 else expression2` expression e.g.

```
if (count(employmentNav/EmpEmployment/compInfoNav/EmpCompensation/startDate) >= count(employmentNav/EmpEmployment/jobInfoNav/EmpJob/startDate)) then mf:foo() else mf:bar()
```

where `mf:foo` and `mf:bar` would be user-defined functions set up with `xsl:function`.

The whole description with talk about loops sounds as if you try to use procedural programming with XSLT, you might want to show us small but representative samples of XML input, output you want together with the rules you want to implement so that we might be able to suggest a more XSLT like approach.